# Present View Controller embedded in Navigation Controller apart of Tab bar controller modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller embedded inside of a navigation controller. This navigation controller is the third item inside of my tab bar controller. I want to present the view controller modally.

This is what I've tried, but it does not run

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    // CameraView is the Storyboard ID of the VC I want to present

    if viewController is EditPreviewVideosViewController {
        if let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraView") {

            // None of this prints
            print()
            print("new vc is allowed")
            print()
            tabBarController.navigationController?.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: {
                print("complete")
            })
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Is your camera VC and your tabBarController in same storyboard ?

Comment: No the tab bar controller is in a different storyboard

Comment: I am asking that both view controller in same STORYBOARD FILE ? or you have multiple storyboards

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, no they are not in the same storyboard file. I have multiple storyboards

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the right navigation controller from tabbarController childs

```
if let nav = tabBarController.viewControllers[tabBarController.selectedIndex] as UINavigationController {

    nav.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: {
        print("complete")
    })
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this code, can u update the answer with the full function in the app Delegate

Comment: this code should replace the line `tabBarController.navigationController?.present({ ... })`

Comment: Okay, i tried that, and i discovered the `if viewController is EditPreviewVideosViewController `is not being ran. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are finding view controller in wrong storyboard

with  this line

```
let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ....
```

It should be

```
let newVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "NameOfYourStoryboardContainsVideo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraView")
```

Now your if will execute correctly

Comment: So do i include the name of the storyboard ID, or the actual name of the storyboard

Comment: First parameter will take NAME of storyboard like `Main`   and second parrameter will accept Storyboard id which is  "CameraView"